# Is it possible to use a variant as a data source for a table?

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a Variant that is storing keys from a Dictionary. I need to put these values into a table but as far as I can tell the data source for a table has to be a range. Is there anyway around this? If not, is there a way to convert my variant to a range?

(Extra details about the Dict and Variant)
Both rely on imported data so there are no fixed values or even number of values, making my issue that much more complicated.

I've tried looking around for answers to this as I am at a complete loss - this is well beyond my current knowledge of vba - but what little I did find didn't seem to work.

Here's the code (only for creating the table but can provide more if needed) without any lines trying to convert the xInput. xInput is the Variant and hashTbl is the Dictionary.

```
ReDim xInput(0 To hashTbl.Count - 1) 'Redefine xInput as hashTbl values

    For i = 0 To hashTbl.Count - 1
        xInput(i) = hashTbl.Keys(i)
    Next i

    Set objTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, xInput, Selection, , xlYes)
    objTable.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2"
```

Of course, I want the table to be populated with the data contained in xInput but all I get is "Runtime Error - 5 Invalid Procedure Call or Argument"

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any use? http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/05/vba-writing-dictionaries-to-worksheet.html

Comment: I think this will work! Thanks :D